# Right click Menulet ObjC

Tags: objective-c, applescript, applescript-objc, mouseleftbuttondown

I was able to create a small Menubar app using ApplescriptObjC, and it works just fine, the menu displays and I am also able to use different icons. Now I have been trying to differentiate between Right and Left clicks, in order to trigger different actions depending on the pressed button. What I would like to do is display the menu when the right mouse button is pressed, and when the left one is pressed, trigger a handler like:

```
on leftButtonPressed_(sender)
    display dialog "Left Button Pressed!"
end leftButtonPressed_
```

Eventually it will be substituted by something more complex. What I have done until now is create a custom class with all the ObjC code required in order to make the Menubar app work. here it is:

MenuBarAppAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MenuBarAppAppDelegate : NSObject {
     NSMenuItem *MenuItem;
     IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;

     NSStatusItem *statusItem;
     NSImage *menuIcon;
     NSImage *menuIconActive;
}
@end
```

MenuBarAppAppDelegate.m

```
#import "MenuBarAppAppDelegate.h"



@implementation MenuBarAppAppDelegate
-(void)dealloc
{
    [menuIcon release];
    [menuIconActive release];
    //[statusItem release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]
                   statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]
                  retain];

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];

    menuIcon= [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"Icon1a" ofType:@"png"]];

    menuIconActive= [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"Icon2a" ofType:@"png"]];

    [statusItem setImage:menuIcon];
    [statusItem setTitle:@""];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [statusItem setEnabled:YES];
    [statusItem setToolTip:@"Togglr"];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];


}






-(void)actMenuIcon{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    menuIcon= [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"AppleLogoFullBlack" ofType:@"png"]];
    menuIconActive= [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"AppleLogoFullWhite" ofType:@"png"]];



    [statusItem setImage:menuIcon];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:menuIconActive];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}
-(void)desMenuIcon{

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    menuIcon= [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"AppleLogoEmptyBlack" ofType:@"png"]];
    menuIconActive= [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"AppleLogoEmptyWhite" ofType:@"png"]];

    [statusItem setImage:menuIcon];
    [statusItem setAlternateImage:menuIconActive];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}

@end
```

My Problem now is that I have no idea how to actually intercept the right and left mouse click, and how to bind it to a applescript handler. Can anyone help me???

Thanks in advance!